# Woocommerce put specific add_action inside specific div

Tags: css, woocommerce, webhooks

Im trying to understand the woocommerce webhooks.

I am working inside of content-single-product.php

I have 2 divs:

```
<div id="div_left"></div>
<div id="div_right"></div>
```

I have now the do_action:

```
/**
         * Hook: woocommerce_after_single_product_summary.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_upsell_display - 15
         * @hooked woocommerce_output_related_products - 20
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary' );
```

As you can see, the web hooks contain multiple actions.

What Im looking to execute is this:

```
<div id="div_left">
woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs - 10
</div>
```

and

```
<div id="div_right">
woocommerce_upsell_display - 15
</div>
```

How do i insert the actions like this?

Because I'm trying now to use remove_action and add_action, but i either get everything inside of the hook, or i get nothing.

I only want to place the specific hook in a specific place.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked by copying template into theme and modify

Comment: no. I already have the page laid out in divs and floats already and its 3/4 of the way there. Only thing holding me back now at this point is the insertion of a specific hook into a specific div

Comment: To change the hook position , you need to modify template - copy this to theme plugins/woocommerce/templates/content-single-product.php and change the position

Comment: I'm already in that page. This is exactly where the editing is taking place right now. I need to know this final piece of the puzzle. Do you know??

Answer (score 0):

Use this to render tabs in your desired location

```
<div id="div_left">
wc_get_template( 'single-product/tabs/tabs.php' );
</div>
```

Remove tabs callback from the action

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 10 );
```

Comment: I have a problem.  When i write first level pages like <? wc_get_template( 'single-product/related.php' ); ?> I can't get them to render. I only see the rendering of ones in a folder like tabs/.  Why is this?

Comment: @WillingLearner where you are writing this?

Comment: in another div on the same page

Comment: You are missing php tag in start - <?php wc_get_template( 'single-product/related.php' ); ?>

Comment: @WillingLearner add below code above the <?php wc_get_template( 'single-product/related.php' ); ?>  https://gist.github.com/mujuonly/28b0056c10d04f23cf890f547b9d4c84

Comment: im sorry but that code doesn't work either. Why would i even have to write all that code as compared to the single line of code that worked fine for /tabs/tabs.php?. Why are the nested pages working but not the ones on the same level?

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can try this.

```
<div id="div_left">
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 10 ); ?>
</div>
<div id="div_right">
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_upsell_display', 15 ); ?>
</div>
```

For example, `do_action` is like `Echo` in PHP, and will echo out in your case `product_data_tabs` from the `after_single_product_summary` field.

Also, you can write `remove_action` for some of elements before calling `do_action`; for example:

```
<?php
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20 ); ?>
<div id="div_left">
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 10 ); ?>
    </div>
    <div id="div_right">
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_upsell_display', 15 ); ?>
    </div>
```

You just have to remove it before rending it.